# data reprojection and the antimeridian

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, antimeridian

I am trying to produce an earthquake map of the south-west pacific ocean area around New Zealand and its surrounding islands.

In order to produce a map which crosses the antimeridian, I took two ASTER dtm products and reprojected them from Pseudo Mercator EPSG:3857 to PDC Mercator EPSG:3832 which is centred on the pacific ocean

[image]

I added my earthquake data in csv format as points in EPSG:3857 and used 'save-as' to save as shapefile and then 'save-as' again to reproject them to EPSG:3832, however they still plot in exactly the same place, completely off from my reprojected dtm and at the wrong scale

[image]

The csv format looks like this (in qgis)

[image]

and they plot perfectly when i'm not trying to cross the antimeridian

[image]

Hopefully someone has an idea of what's going on and how to solve it..

I have also tried to use a layer extent to help when reprojecting the shapefiles but all this seems to do is cause me to lose all the data that is stored in the attribute tables!

Comment: Can you add sample lines of the original CSV file? It might be the coordinates are in lonlat degrees, not EPSG:3857.

Comment: Yes, sorry I hadn't finished the post when i made it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AndreJ guessed, your data is in WGS84, not PseudoMercator. Try with EPSG:4326 instead.

Also, you do not have to use "save as" to actually convert your data, it is possible to reproject on-the-fly, you just have to specify the correct coordinate system for each layer.